# DELETE method not allow in IIS (7)?

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

some how im developing ASp.net mvc application, the DELETE method work fine in VS server, but however, when i test it in an IIS. it's not working and absolutly return a 405 Error..

and currently, I dont know where and how i can get IIS allow my DELETE/PUT HTTP method in my application....

Can some one help me please?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but also keep in mind that PUT/DELETE are not supported by some HTTP proxies, so you might want to use other methods.

Comment: maybe i will implement the POST with extra field if there's no other way around this problem... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the account that your app is using has write access to the web site / virtual directory that your app is running in.  It will also need write access to the folders at the filesystem level.

Comment: how can i set this? beside, im currently using asp.net mvc, so i think it's different than ASP.net form

Comment: You'd set it in the IIS configuration, in the properties of your site / virtual directory.

Comment: Note that it's not common for admins to enable write access.  Like you say in your comment, you would probably be better off using filesystem objects in your app to work with the filesystem if this is any kind of app that will be used widely in various environments.

Answer (score -1):

You can try your HTTP delete method with this  [**http request generator**](http://soft-net.net/sendhttptool.aspx)
; Enter the url -> select delete method -> insert to post section the xml (only if needed) -> press send request.
You will get  detailed report about your request